# TypeORM/MongoDB - sort collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, orm, nosql, typeorm

How do I sort/order a MongoDB collection with TypeORM?
This is hinted by TypeScript, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
const collection = await this.repository.find({
  where: { id: id },
  order: { dateCreated: 'DESC' },
});
```

I couldn't find much in the docs about sorting with MongoDB in TypeORM

**EDIT**:

The source of my problems was the unit test I was the testing the function with. When I got the database dump, then I saw that indeed this code works.

So this question should be closed.

Comment: Your query object looks fine [as per `find` docs](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/find-options#dafe0f5e95e5475d98a9d75a1aa55c17). Maybe refer to the [mongodb-support](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/mongodb#mongodb-support) docs.